# How to Change the Default Chrome Icon in Notifications for a JavaScript Progressive Web App (PWA)

Tags: push-notification, notifications, android-icons

Is it possible to change the default "Chrome icon" in JavaScript? I want to update the icon with a custom one. I am working on a Progressive Web App (PWA) and using the push notification feature. The notification icon shows on desktop, but not on mobile devices.

[Notification chrome icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EczM4.jpg)

My goal is to change the default Chrome desktop icon to a custom one. I've tried various solutions, such as passing the icon URL and badge, but none of them worked. Most of the solutions I found are for Android, but I want to achieve this using JavaScript. I am working with Node.js, JavaScript, Firebase, HTML, and CSS.

[Manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13ny9.png)

[Test Notification Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUwW4.png)